# Laravel Doctrine, (doctrine:schema:update) doesn't create tables for newly added entites

Tags: laravel, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created 3 entites at first. Then I ran 
`php artisan doctrine:schema:create`. 
It created 3 tables in the database. Then I added 4 more new entites. But when I ran `doctrine:schema:update`, it doesn't create new tables from new entites. It just updates the already existing 3 entites, if there are changes.

How do I just create the newly added entities tables?

Answer (score 0):

Besides `doctrine:schema:create` there should also be a `doctrine:schema:update` command which calculates the diff first and only executes SQL queries to sync your schema.

You should be able to run it with the `--dump-sql` option to see which queries will be executed.

Comment: sorry my bad, i was trying to run doctrine:schema:update . but it is not creating new schemas.